# Interpretating combinations formula in a coin flipping example

Tags: probability

If you have all the possible permutations(arrangements) of flipping a fair coin 3 times

HHH
HHT
HTH
HTT
THH
THT
TTH
TTT

and you want to know how many there are that contain two heads, you could use the combinations formula 3C2 to get 3 which is the number of arrangements that contain 2 heads in them

I'm having a problem of interpreting what 3C2 means in this context. Combinations involve making a selection of 2 in this case from 3 distinct things. So what does the 3 and 2 stand for in this selection of 2 heads from 3 flips?

It doesn't make sense from a combinations point of view where you cannot have a selection of 2 of the same things(heads) or that the arrangements all count as one e.g HHT = HTH = THH etc..!

It's probably that way I'm thinking when I use that formula that is messing things up. The way I think is - I need the number of arrangements that have 2 head from 3 flips, so I see the formula as

(no. of flips)C(no. of heads) = 3C2

2 should mean a [selection of 2] and not [2 heads], right?

I'm probably making it sound more confusing than it actually is!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you have three placeholders, and making a sequence is filling them in with either $H$ or $T$.

The number of ways to get $2$ heads is the number of ways to decide which two (2) of the three (3) placeholders are going to contain a head.

Comment: ... which is the same as deciding which *one* of *three* slots gets $T$.